# Observing and notifying

Tags: java

I have to implement a notification service and send a message with some new content about music.

```
    public class FilterByMusic implements Observer {

    private String music;
    private Observable observe;

    public FilterByMusic(String music, Observable observe) {
        this.music = music;
        this.observe = observe;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

I made another class which extends Observable with this method

```
    public void newMusicNotify() {
    //new music here.. 
    this.setChanged();
    this.notifyObservers(music);
    }
```

So it works if there's a new music it notifies all observers which observe that object. But now I want to have a filter, which only sends a message to an observer if it's by an specific music which I have as parameter at FilterByMusic. I have an observer which wants all new music notified and an observer who wants only a specific music (because he don't likes all kinds of music) how can i do that?

I appreciate all your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like has more than one `Observable` use some kind of `Container` like `Map` (i.e. `map["rockObserver"]`), and into method `update(Observable o, Object arg)` use `switch` depends on `music`.

Comment: So it sends the notification to all observers and the filtering get's handled in the update method. I thought kind of if the music is not the music the observer wants (given in the filter constructor), then I don't send that message, otherwise I send it and print it in the update method.

Is there a way to do that? THANK YOU

Comment: In `update()` method you could use `if(this.music is what observable like){// notify }`

Comment: @Michael You could wrap many SpecificObservable in one BigObservable. In bigObservable.addObserver subscribe observer to specificObservable you like.

Comment: That sounds great, but I don't know how to do it exactly. At the moment I have on unique Observable which sends the notifications, and different classes which implement observers. 1 Observer should get all notifactions of new music, the other should only get by filter new music. I think your solution could help me, but I don't how. Could you maybe write an example, it would help me alot please

Answer (score -1):

I would propose that instead of using Java's oberver interfaces, just do your own. This way, you will be much more flexible.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question